# Как уменьшить количество зависимостей в классе

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, php7

Например у меня есть метод, который выводит статистику. От вытягивает данные из азных таблиц базы данных, соответственно используется множество классов репозиториев. В результате конструктор выглядит так:

```
public function __construct(
    UsersModel $usersModel,
    StatisticsCampaignRepository $statisticsCampaignRepository,
    UserRecipientsRepository $userRecipientsRepository,
    LandingVerifyStatisticsRepository $landingVerifyStatisticsRepository,
    CampaignsRepository $campaignsRepository,
    UserApiStatisticsRepository $userApiStatisticsRepository,
    ChromeVerifyStatisticsRepository $chromeVerifyStatisticsRepository,
    UserActivityStatisticsRepository $userActivityStatisticsRepository
) {
    $this->usersModel = $usersModel;
    $this->statisticsCampaignRepository = $statisticsCampaignRepository;
    $this->userRecipientsRepository = $userRecipientsRepository;
    $this->landingVerifyStatisticsRepository = $landingVerifyStatisticsRepository;
    $this->campaignsRepository = $campaignsRepository;
    $this->userApiStatisticsRepository = $userApiStatisticsRepository;
    $this->chromeVerifyStatisticsRepository = $chromeVerifyStatisticsRepository;
    $this->userActivityStatisticsRepository = $userActivityStatisticsRepository;
}
```

Как можно уменьшить количество зависимостей в этом класе, не создавая несколько оберток, которые будут просто вызывать методы из нескольких репозиториев?

Answer (score 1):

Короткий ответ: никак.

Промежуточный класс, который мог бы предоставлять доступ к разным репозиториям — это паттерн *Реестр* (*Regisry*). Если вы используете инверсию зависимостей, он вам и правда не нужен, потому что все эти репозитории переползут в его конструктор.

Ваша проблема может быть решена на другом уровне. Какие здесь есть варианты?

1. Подсистему отчётов и статистики иногда выносят из приложения и реализуют с помощью специализированных средств — [Fast Reports](https://www.fastreport.ru/ru/), [Reporting Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/reporting-services/create-deploy-and-manage-mobile-and-paginated-reports?view=sql-server-ver15). Эти средства включают визуальный редактор отчётов и экспорт в HTML, PDF, XLS, плюс ещё десяток популярных форматов. Вы в своём приложении просто вызываете эти сервисы из своего кода.

   В чём плюс? Обычно в том, что редактор отчётов в таких системах очень
   продвинутый. Отчёты могут делать даже не программисты, хотя иногда для важных
   вещей лучше самому написать SQL руками. Набор отчётов можно менять независимо
   от программы. Минус — возможно, придётся писать много SQL. Иногда отчёты будут
   переставать работать после очередной миграции базы.
2. Можно все методы отчётов и статистики переместить в отдельный репозиторий только для чтения. Обычно `XxxRepository` означает, что класс будет работать только с объектами `Xxx`, но это соглашение. В действительности, репозиторий может работать с несколькими таблицами, а иногда даже и инкапсулировать в себе несколько источников данных.

   Репозиторий статистики может собирать данные из десятка таблиц.
3. Можно развернуть саму задачу. Вместо того, чтобы создавать класс, который собирает всю статистику, вы описываете интерфейс, который возвращает данные в виде списка показателей и их значений. Модуль статистики ищет все классы, которые реализуют этот интерфейс и вызывает у них метод `getStatistics`. А каждый класс подтягивает три или четыре *своих* репозитория. Это решение немного похоже на создание посредников, но в действительности здесь другой уровень гибкости. Один раз написав код показа статистики, вы можете добавлять новые показатели, не меняя его.

   Ваш код становится открытым для расширения, будучи закрытым для изменения. Это как раз 
   Opened-closed principle из SOLID.